# Powershell script on VM cannot create files or folders

Tags: powershell, xunit

I am currently using a VM to run powershell scripts that  run Xunit.runner.console and send the output to a .html file . I have run into an issue that on the VM when i run the scripts it will cannot create the file or folder. when i do this on my local machine there is no issue the file is created with the xunit output. I have tried to see if its a permissions issue but cannot find any that would stop me from creating the file. I have use the -Force but this does not allow Xunit to write to the file.

Any help is much appreciated

**This is the Powershell script that runs:**

```
#$FolderCreate =New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\resultsfolder
#$FileCreate=New-Item "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New folder\Results $(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy).html" -ItemType file
$Location=Set-Location -Path "C:\Tests\Powershell Test Scripts"

$Runner= .\XunitRunnerLocation.ps1  "C:\Tests\TrueFalse Test\bin\Debug\TrueFalse Tests.dll" -html "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New folder\Results $(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy).html"
```

The Below Error i think is related to my test to AssertFalse Which will cause the test to fail

```
xunit.console.exe :     TrueFalse_Tests.True_False_Tests.Assert_Fail [FAIL]
At C:\Tests\Powershell Test Scripts\XunitRunnerLocation.ps1:5 char:1
+ & $runner $testAssembly
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (    TrueFalse_T...ert_Fail [FAIL]:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Comment: What happens? Is there an error? With the line that creates the folder commented out I would expect it to not create the folder.

Comment: Do you get the same error on your desktop where the HTML report creates successfully?

Comment: Yes same error. Only difference is on my machine the file is created with no issue. And on the VM it wont Create the file. Not sure if its file access or the script is blocked for creating files and folders.

Comment: Does the folder already exist? Because you currently have the line that creates the folder commented out.

Comment: Yes the current Folder already exists. The 2 lines commented out are lines i was trying to use to get around the issue, they will Force create the file and folders but the Xunit.runner.console cannot write to the created .html file, it gets created as a Blank html file.

Comment: Is the script being run as an administrator?

Comment: Yes being Run as Admin